# create new process in python which should be killed after completion of task

Tags: python, multithreading

I am creating multiple new processes(via loop) in which I am executing some function.

```
p = Process(target=<>, args=())
p.start()
```

My parent process is continuously running and creating the process.
Looks like new child process is not getting killed(but sleeping) after completion of their respective task. How can I create new process in python which should be killed after completion of task.

Thanks,
Shantanu

Comment: If your parent process is continuously creating the process, have you considered using `Pool`?

Comment: You can use `p.join()` to wait for it to finish, but it's probably waiting for user input or something. Try creating the process with `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`

Comment: @kkpattern, My use case is that all new process should be getting killed once complete. And I am creating only 7 process in a minute.

Comment: @Wolph: As per my understanding join is just enable parent to wait untill all child processes finishes.

Comment: @shantanu: If your concern is that if the new processes are not killed, there will be too much processes, then a `Pool` can help you since the number of the processes is limited.

Comment: @kkpattern, Agree that using pool will limit the number of process. But that is not the intent of this question.